# mysqli_real_escape_string brinda la misma protección a consultas preparadas

Tags: php, mysqli

En la aplicación que estoy haciendo la cual se publica y obtiene datos por medio de *HTTP REQUEST* he hecho pruebas de *1=1* etc... y no pasa nada, solo dice que no existe el dato consultado, entonces no sé si es necesario hacer consultas preparadas y preferir utilizar el escape *mysqli_real_escape_string* es seguro?

```js
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['age']);
```

Comment: Por que hay casos vulnerables que no cubre `mysqli_real_escape_string()` es preferible la sentencia preparada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no deberías jamás preferir escapar caracteres a usar consultas preparadas para prevenir *Inyección SQL*.

Los motivos son varios:

1. Aunque el escape de caracteres es una herramienta de seguridad, no es necesario si usas consultas preparadas, las cuales ya se encargan de escapar lo que haya que escapar. Es decir, las consultas preparadas por sí mismas suponen ya la protección que estarías buscando con escape string. Es importante entender que **en cada nivel debes aplicar la seguridad que se necesite**. Por poner un ejemplo, hay quienes aplican filtros html a datos que nunca van a mostrar en pantalla. Si no vas a mostrar esos datos en pantalla, ¿para qué aplicas un filtro como si los fueras a mostrar en pantalla?
2. Escapar caracteres puede darte problemas, por ejemplo si no tienes la codificación bien definida o si estás trabajando con hash, contraseñas, etc.
3. Las consultas preparadas **son más rápidas**, porque el manejador traza un plan para esa consulta, de modo que cuando la misma se repita irá más rápido. Es como tener que ir a un sitio varias veces, generalmente la primera vez llegas más lento porque vas más pendiente de las señales, te puedes perder, etc, pero las otras veces llegas más rápido, porque ya conoces la ruta.
4. Sobre el hermano mayor de `mysqli_real_escape_string` [pesa una sombra](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187/5587982) que, aunque es cierto que esta función fue mejorada en las nuevas versiones de PHP hay una sombra de duda. En la pregunta citada se demuestra un caso de Inyección aunque los datos fueron escapados.

Si te interesa profundizar un poco más sobre los motivos para no preferir escapar, te recomiendo el breve post [*Why should I use prepared statements if escaping is safe?*](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/why_should_i_use_prepared_statements_if_escaping_is_safe) de @YourCommonSense, uno de los usuarios más experimentados sobre mysqli y PDO.